# return result depending on row count for column

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have table orders

```
Orders{
  id
  user_id
  status
  date
}
```

I need to return the results as if theres an orders for the same user more than 5 times
like if theres order like this

```
ID User_ID Status Date
1  1       Pending xxxxx
2  1       Pending xxxxx
3  1       Pending xxxxx
4  1       Pending xxxxx
5  1       Pending xxxxx
6  2       Pending xxxxx
7  3       Pending xxxxx
8  2       Pending xxxxx
9  1       Pending xxxxx
```

the result will be all the orders from the user id = 1 cause theres more than 5 orders he made.
how I can do it using active records ?

Answer (score 1):

Select * from Table 
where [User_ID] in (Select [User_ID] from Table group by [User_ID] having count(*) > 5)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from orders 
where user_id in (Select user_id from orders group by user_id having count(1)>=5)
```

Comment: Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime...

Comment: He did ask for active record syntax though.

Comment: for active records you can add where clause in sub query Select * from orders 
where user_id in (Select user_id from orders where status='Pending' group by user_id having count(1)>=5)

Answer (score 0):

In your model you can pass the userid and get results of a particular user

Model

```
function get_orders($userid)
     {
         $this->db->where('user_id',$userid);
         $query =$this->db->get('orders');
         return $query->result();  
     }
```

Controller

```
function orders($userid){

$result=$this->model->get_orders($userid);
if($result){

foreach ($result as $row){
echo $row->id."<br/>";
echo $row->user_id."<br/>";
....
..
}

}

}
```